# How do I assign a value in numpy with advanced boolean indexing?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, array-broadcasting

I'm trying to broadcast a one-dimensional output to a three-dimensional array, using boolean indexing. I have an array I'd like to assign to:

```
output_array = np.zeros((2,4,3))
```

And then some sets of boolean arrays that I am using to do the indexing:

```
dim0_bool = np.array([True, True])
dim0_dim1_bool = np.array([[True, True, True, False],
                           [False, True, True, True]])
dim0_dim2_bool = np.array([[True, True, False],
                           [False, True, True]])
```

From these I can construct a three-dimensional boolean index array, and assign a value to the output array using it:

```
output_array_idx = np.einsum('i, ij, ik -> ijk',
                            dim0_bool,
                            dim0_dim1_bool, 
                            dim0_dim2_bool)
output_array[output_array_idx] = 1.0
```

Which all works fine, and gives the expected output of:

```
array([[[1., 1., 0.],
        [1., 1., 0.],
        [1., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 1.],
        [0., 1., 1.],
        [0., 1., 1.]]])
```

What I'd really like to do, though, (and I'm not sure how feasible this is) is to broadcast a one-dimensional array to the indexed elements of `output_array`. For example:

```
dim2_output = np.array([1.0, 2.0])
```

Then:

```
output_array[output_array_idx] = dim2_output
```

which would ideally give:

```
array([[[1., 2., 0.],
        [1., 2., 0.],
        [1., 2., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 2.],
        [0., 1., 2.],
        [0., 1., 2.]]])
```

This doesn't work as-is because indexing `output_array` by `output_array_idx` reduces it to a single-dimension array, and so I can't assign `dim2_output` (which is single-dimension, but a different length) to it.

Hope that's clear and any help (or suggestions as to how this might be better approached) much appreciated.

Comment: What if `dim0_dim2_bool` were : `[[True, True, False], [True, True, True]]`?

Comment: Yes - it's a good point - but in this case I know that the input won't violate that rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could construct a `[1,2,1,2,...]` array of matching size.

`np.resize` does the correct replication:

```
In [741]: np.resize([1,2],12)
Out[741]: array([1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2])
```

or `repeat`:

```
In [744]: np.array([[1,2]]).repeat(6,axis=0).ravel()
Out[744]: array([1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2])
```

Comment: Yes - thanks - I guess that is going to be the best way overall.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pretty dirty approach. You can set up the the `output_array` to contain *indices* for the `dim2_output`. The drawback is that the `output_array` no longer lives up to it's name, and you need to make two copies - one for indices and one for the result.

The tactic is to initialize array of `nans`, fill ones based on your boolean mask and us `np.nancumsum` to recover the indices.

```
import numpy as np

# init output array with nans instead of zeros
output_array = np.full((2, 4, 3), np.nan)

dim0_bool = np.array([True, True])
dim0_dim1_bool = np.array([[True, True, True, False], [False, True, True, True]])
dim0_dim2_bool = np.array([[True, True, False], [False, True, True]])


output_array_idx = np.einsum(
    "i, ij, ik -> ijk", dim0_bool, dim0_dim1_bool, dim0_dim2_bool
)

# make the output array contain indices for dim2_output
output_array[output_array_idx] = 1
output_array = (np.nancumsum(output_array, -1) - 1) * output_array
output_array[np.isnan(output_array)] = -1

# append to work with index manipulations 0
dim2_output = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 0])

result = dim2_output[output_array.astype(np.int)]


# array([[[1., 2., 0.],
# [1., 2., 0.],
# [1., 2., 0.],
# [0., 0., 0.]],

# [[0., 0., 0.],
# [0., 1., 2.],
# [0., 1., 2.],
# [0., 1., 2.]]])
```

Comment: Thanks - I might not do it that way just for reasons of readability, but it definitely wins the prize for creativity.

Comment: I would not advise that either. Perhaps you should consider using `einsum` on dims 0 and 1, and reserving dim 2 for indexing from some output array.